# Not getting the lock icon in the recent apps list

Tags: 7.0-nougat, stock-android

I came to know that there is a lock icon on every app in the recent apps list in the overview in android that allows us to pin some apps to the list.

I am using Android 7.0 , but I am not getting any such icon there. See this screenshot :
[image]

Is there any hidden setting in Android by which this functionality can be enabled ?

Comment: https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-make-use-of-the-android-nougat-recent-apps-lock/

Comment: I think you haven't understood my question properly. My question is how to enable that feature, because the lock icon is not there on any of the apps (see the above screenshot).

Comment: Did you mean screen pinning? Open Settings-> Security & location->Screen pinning.  Enable it. Also, enable 'ask for pattern before unpinning'. These settings are from android 9.0. And, for 7.0 you can search for screen pinning from search option top-right of settings page.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46613909/lock-an-app-on-the-recent-apps-screen-prevent-user-from-closing-it-when-certai

Comment: @RahulGopi no, this is not about screen pinning. Now I don't remember if I had this feature on stock Nexus 5 (perhaps not because it's too old), but per-app lock is there on the "recent apps" when I started using Lineage OS.

Comment: @AndrewT. I am running also 9.0 stock android, also don't remember the same used in Oreo and nougat. But. for custom UI devices like xiaomi, have still such options.

Comment: No, no, I know very well about the screen pinning feature. I am talking about the tiny lock icon beside the cross mark on the top bar of the recent apps list, by which we can lock individual apps to the recent apps list. The link which you provided me at first. My question is 'how to enable that feature' ? That is by default, not enabled in my phone.